# Go logger decorator with gorilla mux

Tags: logging, go

I'm new to Go and playing around with mux for creating some REST APIs following http://thenewstack.io/make-a-restful-json-api-go/. While it works fine mostly, I don't see console logging as expected using the Logger decorator that uses log.Println to log the HTTP requests.

Am I missing something? Also, it looks like Logger is called when ranging over the routes list, is this the right way to log for each request?

Answer (score 0):

The logs by default stream to `stderr`. If you wanted to see the output of your server ( for example, named "testAPI" ), you will need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` (your terminal):

```
// If already compiled
/path/to/testAPI 2>&1
// Without building / installing
go run testAPI.go 2>&1
```

If you simply want it to log to a log file:

```
// If already compiled
/path/to/testAPI 2> /path/to/logs/testAPI.log
// Without building / installing
go run testAPI.go 2> /path/to/logs/testAPI.log
```

[The pkg/log source](http://golang.org/src/log/log.go?s=2527:2566#L58) defines the output internally:

```
var std = New(os.Stderr, "", LstdFlags)
```

Finally, from [the standard lib docs](http://golang.org/pkg/log):

> Package log implements a simple logging package. It defines a type,
>   Logger, with methods for formatting output. It also has a predefined
>   'standard' Logger accessible through helper functions Print[f|ln],
>   Fatal[f|ln], and Panic[f|ln], which are easier to use than creating a
>   Logger manually. That logger writes to standard error and prints the
>   date and time of each logged message. The Fatal functions call
>   os.Exit(1) after writing the log message. The Panic functions call
>   panic after writing the log message.